# Should a period or comma be used before "instead" in "Because bananas are not orange, instead, bananas are yellow"?

Tags: commas, periods, comma-splices

> Joe: This banana is orange.
> Niel: No, this banana is yellow.
> Joe: Why do you say that?
> Niel: Because bananas are not orange, instead, bananas are yellow.
> Joe: You think in a funny way.

Another way Niel could say the same thing is "Because bananas are not orange. Instead, bananas are yellow."

Should we keep the period before 'instead' or not? I am confused.

Comment: I would suggest a dash when reproducing informal speech. However, a native speaker would say "Bananas aren't orange, they're yellow!"

Comment: It seems a matter of opinion. Some people say sentences cannot be joined by commas, others don't mind.

Comment: The word *instead* is interrupting the sentence.

Comment: @Stuart F I'm sure the thread/s on 'comma splices' refines/refine that to 'Some people say that sentences cannot be joined by commas; others say that in special cases, this is too prescriptivist.'

Comment: I would probably use a semicolon or hyphen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Because bananas are not orange" is not a clause explaining why "instead, bananas are yellow." Instead, it's the answer to the question "Why do you say that?"; it serves to explain why Niel has *said* that bananas are yellow. So you do need a period there.

Comment: A semicolon would also do, and some might argue it's preferable.